# Animation bug with NavMeshAgent in 2D game(using NavMeshPlus)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

The animation begins to quickly switch during corner passages. Most likely, the problem is that the values change too quickly. However, I can't understand how to fix this (In code or animator).
Someone had same issue ?

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAnimationHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator _animator;
    private NavMeshAgent _agent;
    

    private void Awake()
    { 
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _agent = GetComponentInParent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Animate();
    }

    private void Animate()
    {
        bool isMoving = _agent.velocity.magnitude > 0.1f;

        _animator.SetBool("Moving", isMoving);

        if (isMoving ) 
        {
            Vector3 movementDirection = _agent.velocity.normalized;
            _animator.SetFloat("X", movementDirection.x);
            _animator.SetFloat("Y", movementDirection.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or tips, maybe someone had this problem and solved it

Comment: Loose the conditions for changes, e.g. switch from bottom to left when x > 1.1y